# How to draw a Spiral & Arc Shape Curves using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, maps

I am trying to draw a spiral & arc shapes using pygame.
The data I want to draw is of OpenDRIVE maps. It has two types of curves.

Arc has same starting and ending curvatures, however, spiral has different start and ending curvatures. See a sample map data here: *http://www.opendrive.org/tools/CulDeSac.xodr*.
([Map image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0tx3.png)

pygame allows only one function to draw curves which requires the boundary rectangle and start/end angles to draw arcs. See *http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc*.

I want to know how to draw both type of curves(arc & spiral) using pygame.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There aren't built in methods to do this in pygame so you'll have to come up with your own. Also, by spiral do you mean an actual spiral or the cul-de-sac shape shown in the image you've linked?

Comment: @WyattIsrael by spiral I mean the cul-de-sac shape. This shape is composed of spiral and arc shapes as you can find in the sample data file I have provided.

Comment: Looking at the [OpenDRIVE specification](http://www.opendrive.org/docs/OpenDRIVEFormatSpecRev1.4H.pdf) it looks like <spiral> is defined as clothoids (aka euler spirals). I would check out the javascript code on the [wiki page for euler spirals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) for some inspiration. There is definitely nothing built into pygame to handle this.